# Refactor this function to use "return" consistently getting this issue in sonarqube any idea how to resolve it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sonarqube

```
test(a,b)=>{
 if(a === b){
  return `<p>test</p>`;
  }
}
```

** Refactor this function to use "return" consistently getting this issue in sonarqube any idea how to resolve it? **

Comment: You are not returning anything when if condition fails. So, it's probably complaining about that. Try adding a `return null` outside the if block

Comment: so ideally this should be                                                                                                                                   test(a,b)=>{
 if(a === b){
  return `<p>test</p>`;
  }return null
}

Comment: Better still:  test(a,b) => return((a===b)? '<p>test</p>': null);

Comment: `const test = (a, b) => a === b ? \`<p>test</p>\` : \`\`` or `const test = (a, b) => a === b ? \`<p>test</p>\` : null`